# Splitting [filereader] between [java] and [javascript]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Each of [java+filereader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filereader+java) ([filereader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filereader)) and [javascript+filereader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filereader+javascript) combo has just over 200 questions. I think it's a good idea to rename them to match their specific languages... [java-filereader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-filereader) and [javascript-filereader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-filereader).

Comment: The are other users of the tag (less than 200), but I haven't looked at them.

Comment: Do we have a common precedent of splitting tags for [foo] (where 'foo' is a named feature in two languages) into [language-one-foo] and [language-two-foo]?

Comment: Not sure if I'd call it a *common precedent*, but in cases where there are conflicts, it does make sense.

Comment: You haven't mentioned **why** it's a good idea - what problem does it solve? Presumably every question has already been tagged with either `java` or `javascript`, so there should be no confusion.

Comment: @slugster I was thinking a worthy tag is a tag people would be willing to subscribe to. I would be surprised if people would be interested in a function/class name regardless of which language it's available in. That is, a tag should be remain meaningful even if others tags are removed. Am I missing something?